# Alternative to python hash function for arbitrary objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

In python2.7, I'm successfully using `hash()` to place objects into buckets stored persistently on disk. A mockup code looks like this:

```
class PersistentDict(object):
  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    bucket_index = (hash(key)&0xffffffff) % self.bucket_count
    self._store_to_bucket(bucket_index, key, value)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    bucket_index = (hash(key)&0xffffffff) % self.bucket_count
    return self._fetch_from_bucket(bucket_index)[key]
```

In python3, `hash()` uses a random or fixed salt, which makes it unusable/suboptimal for this [1]. Apparently, it's not possible to use a [fixed salt for specific invocations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38001874/5349916). So, I need an alternative:

- Must be stable across interpreter invocations
- May require parameters supplied at execution time, e.g. setting a salt in the call
- Must support arbitrary objects (anything supported by `dict`/`set`)

I've already tried using hash functions from [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) (slow!) and checksums from [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.adler32) (apparently not ideal for hashing, but meh) which work fine with strings/bytes. However, they work *only* on bytes-like objects, whereas `hash()` works with almost everything.

---

[1] Using `hash()` to identify buckets is either:

- Not reliable across interpreter invocations, if salts are random
- Prevents applications from using the random salting feature, if salts are fixed
- Unusable if two `PersistentDict`s were created with different salts

Comment: The random hash only applies to `str`, `bytes` and `datetime` objects. You'd only need an alternative for those types.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! I guess str and bytes can be covered by zlib/hashlib. I'll see whether I can find something fast for datetime.

Comment: `str(datetime)` should suffice; that gets you the ISO8601 format with microseconds and optionally the timezone if attached, and then you have a `str`...

Comment: I'd still test thoroughly and look for alternatives if timezones are involved however; I suspect that timezone subtleties could lead to equal ISO8601 representations for otherwise different timezone objects, in ways that could matter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It seems that salting also applies to ``None``. I have yet to find a suitable solution for hashable containers, without restricting it to ``repr`` or the like.

Comment: For `None` the `__hash__` implementation is inherited from `type`, which produces the hash of the memory address of the object, since this varies from interpreter to interpreter process, the value can appear random. This means that setting `PYTHONHASHSEED` **will not affect the hash value of `None`**, like it would for types to which the seed does apply.

Comment: So I guess I have to modify my first comment to include type objects (custom classes and built-in) and `None`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344515/python-consistent-hash-replacement

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using a combination of `hash` and `zlib.adler32`. The most straightforward implementation is this:

```
def hashkey(obj, salt=0):
  """
  Create a key suitable for use in hashmaps

  :param obj: object for which to create a key
  :type: str, bytes, :py:class:`datetime.datetime`, object
  :param salt: an optional salt to add to the key value
  :type salt: int
  :return: numeric key to `obj`
  :rtype: int
  """
  if obj is None:
    return 0
  if isinstance(obj, str):
    return zlib.adler32(obj.encode(), salt) & 0xffffffff
  elif isinstance(obj, bytes):
    return zlib.adler32(obj, salt) & 0xffffffff
  elif isinstance(obj, datetime_type):
    return zlib.adler32(str(obj).encode(), salt) & 0xffffffff
  return hash(obj) & 0xffffffff
```

With Python 3.4.3, this is a lot slower than calling plain `hash`, which takes roughly 0.07 usec. For a regular object, `hashkey` takes ~1.0 usec instead. 0.8 usec for `bytes` and 0.7 for `str`.

Overhead is roughly as follows:

- 0.1 usec for the function call (`hash(obj)` vs `def pyhash(obj): return hash(obj)`)
- 0.2 usec to 0.5 usec for selecting the hash function via `isinstance`
- 0.75 usec for `zlib.adler32` or `zlib.crc32` vs `hash`: ~0.160 usec vs ~ 0.75 usec (adler and crc are +/- 4 usec)
- 0.15 usec for `obj.encode()` of `str` objects (`"foobar"`)
- 1.5 usec for `str(obj).encode()` of `datetime.datetime` objects

The most optimization comes from ordering of the `if` statements. If one mostly expects plain objects, the following is the fastest I could come up with:

```
def hashkey_c(obj, salt=0):
  if obj.__class__ in hashkey_c.types:
    if obj is None:
      return 0
    if obj.__class__ is str:
      return zlib.adler32(obj.encode(), salt) & 0xffffffff
    elif obj.__class__ is bytes:
      return zlib.adler32(obj, salt) & 0xffffffff
    elif obj.__class__ is datetime_type:
      return zlib.adler32(str(obj).encode(), salt) & 0xffffffff
  return hash(obj) & 0xffffffff
hashkey_c.types = {str, bytes, datetime_type, type(None)}
```

Total time: ~0.7 usec for `str` and `bytes`, abysmal for `datetime`, 0.35 usec for objects, ints, etc. Using a `dict` to map type to hash comparable, if one uses an explicit check on the `dict` keys (aka types) separately (i.e. not `obj.__class__ in hashkey.dict_types` but `obj.__class__ in hashkey.explicit_dict_types`).

---

Some additional notes:

- `hash` is not stable across interpreter starts for any object using the default `__hash__` implementation, including `None`
- It does not work properly for immutable containers (which define `__hash__`) containing a salted type, e.g. `(1, 2, 'three')`

Comment: As of python3.6 or so this is not working.  It is not stable across different interpreter executions.  E.g. try hashkey(None).

Comment: @NealYoung Thanks for checking. It seems ``hash(None)`` is salted at least since Python3.4 - I've added this case now. I also realised that hashable containers, such as Tuple, would require special casing as well.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative is [`xxhash`](https://github.com/ifduyue/python-xxhash). It provides fast integer hashes (as Python's hash), but they are consistent across multiple runs and machines:

```py
import xxhash
print(xxhash.xxh32_intdigest('hash me please'))
print(xxhash.xxh64_intdigest('hash me please'))
print(xxhash.xxh128_intdigest('hash me please'))

obj = [0, 1, 2]
print(xxhash.xxh64_intdigest(str(obj)))
print(xxhash.xxh64_intdigest(str(obj), seed=0))
print(xxhash.xxh64_intdigest(str(obj), seed=42))

'''
Prints:
  465606393
  6686454294630346756
  110192986912562192471431245034848549222
  11514819435353980464
  11514819435353980464
  11772420285327955252
'''
```

Since it hashes strings, for arbitrary objects you may hash `str(your_object)` or `repr(your_object)`. You can also set an optional seed parameter that defaults to zero, as shown in the example.

Yet another alternative is [`pyhash`](https://github.com/flier/pyfasthash). It works fine on Linux, but after some bad experiences installing it on Windows machines, I recommend `xxhash` which works well on all platforms and is even faster than `pyhash` for some small examples that I tested.

Answer (score 0):

We use [this](https://github.com/rwth-i6/sisyphus/blob/83d4f2322bdbee61e82460c384b855fee50dc48b/sisyphus/hash.py#L22) code for our [workflow manager Sisyphus](https://github.com/rwth-i6/sisyphus), where we use hashes to store the outputs of jobs on disks, based on input parameters, thus we hash the input parameters.

Specifically:

```py
def short_hash(obj,
               length=12,
               chars='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    """
    :param object obj:
    :param int length:
    :param str|T chars:
    :rtype: str|T
    """
    h = hashlib.sha256(sis_hash_helper(obj)).digest()
    h = int.from_bytes(h, byteorder='big', signed=False)
    ls = []
    for i in range(length):
        ls.append(chars[int(h % len(chars))])
        h = h // len(chars)
    return ''.join(ls)


def get_object_state(obj):
    """
    Export current object status
    Comment: Maybe obj.__reduce__() is a better idea? is it stable for hashing?
    """

    if hasattr(obj, '__getnewargs_ex__'):
        args = obj.__getnewargs_ex__()
    elif hasattr(obj, '__getnewargs__'):
        args = obj.__getnewargs__()
    else:
        args = None

    if hasattr(obj, '__sis_state__'):
        state = obj.__sis_state__()
    elif hasattr(obj, '__getstate__'):
        state = obj.__getstate__()
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        state = obj.__dict__
    elif hasattr(obj, '__slots__'):
        state = {k: getattr(obj, k) for k in obj.__slots__ if hasattr(obj, k)}
    else:
        assert args is not None, "Failed to get object state of: %s" % repr(obj)
        state = None

    if args is None:
        return state
    else:
        return args, state


def sis_hash_helper(obj):
    """
    Takes most object and tries to convert the current state into bytes.
    :param object obj:
    :rtype: bytes
    """

    # Store type to ensure it's unique
    byte_list = [type(obj).__qualname__.encode()]

    # Using type and not isinstance to avoid derived types
    if isinstance(obj, bytes):
        byte_list.append(obj)
    elif obj is None:
        pass
    elif type(obj) in (int, float, bool, str, complex):
        byte_list.append(repr(obj).encode())
    elif type(obj) in (list, tuple):
        byte_list += map(sis_hash_helper, obj)
    elif type(obj) in (set, frozenset):
        byte_list += sorted(map(sis_hash_helper, obj))
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        # sort items to ensure they are always in the same order
        byte_list += sorted(map(sis_hash_helper, obj.items()))
    elif isfunction(obj):
        # Handle functions
        # Not a nice way to check if the given function is a lambda function, but the best I found
        # assert not isinstance(lambda m: m, LambdaType) is true for all functions
        assert obj.__name__ != '<lambda>', "Hashing of lambda functions is not supported"
        byte_list.append(sis_hash_helper((obj.__module__, obj.__qualname__)))
    elif isclass(obj):
        byte_list.append(sis_hash_helper((obj.__module__, obj.__qualname__)))
    elif hasattr(obj, '_sis_hash'):
        # sis job or path object
        return obj._sis_hash()
    else:
        byte_list.append(sis_hash_helper(get_object_state(obj)))

    byte_str = b'(' + b', '.join(byte_list) + b')'
    if len(byte_str) > 4096:
        # hash long outputs to avoid arbitrary long return values. 4096 is just
        # picked because it looked good and not optimized,
        # it's most likely not that important.
        return hashlib.sha256(byte_str).digest()
    else:
        return byte_str
```